# Do there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$ $\text{mod } p^2$ for fixed a?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I noticed that Hardy and Wright in their "An Introduction to Theory of Numbers"(sixth edition) have asked the following:

> Is it ever true that $$2^{p-1}\equiv 1 \bmod p^2 \tag{*}\;\;\;?$$

They have pointed out that for $p=1093$ there is a solution to $(*)$ .But they have stated that such $p$ are sparse .

**Question:** Do there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $a^{p-1}\equiv 1$ $\text{mod } p^2$? For some fixed $a\in Z^\mathbb{+}$ for $a>2$?  Sorry if my question is absolutely trivial.

Comment: This is related to [Wieferich primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime): *Despite a number of extensive searches, the only known Wieferich primes to date are 1093 and 3511. (sequence [A001220](http://oeis.org/A001220) in OEIS).*

Comment: It  turns out my question is hilarious.Sorry about that.I am voting to close.Thanks.

Comment: Why? You asked for $a>2$. See here for [Generalized Wieferich primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient#Generalized_Wieferich_primes)... Gottfried Helms put a paper on the wiki page: [Fermat-/Euler-quotients $(a^{p-1}-1)/p^k$ with arbirtrary $k$](go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question is related to [Wieferich primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wieferich_prime), which represent the case if $a=2$:

> *Despite a number of extensive searches, the only known Wieferich primes to date are 1093 and 3511. (sequence [A001220](http://oeis.org/A001220) in OEIS).*

You asked for the more general case $a>2$. See here for [Generalized Wieferich primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_quotient#Generalized_Wieferich_primes). Here's the table of known examples:

\begin{eqnarray}
a&  p&  \text{OEIS sequence}\\
2 & 1093, 3511 & A001220\\
3&  11, 1006003&  A014127\\
5&  2, 20771, 40487, 53471161, &&\\
&1645333507, 6692367337, 188748146801 & A123692\\
7&  5, 491531 & A123693\\
11&  71 & \\
13&  2, 863, 1747591 & A128667\\
17&  2, 3, 46021, 48947, 478225523351 & A128668\\
19&  3, 7, 13, 43, 137, 63061489  &A090968\\
23&  13, 2481757, 13703077, 15546404183, 2549536629329 & A128669\\
\end{eqnarray}

[Gottfried Helms](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1714/gottfried-helms) had a paper on that: 
[Fermat-/Euler-quotients $(a^{p-1}-1)/p^k$ with arbirtrary $k$](http://go.helms-net.de/math/expdioph/fermatquotients.pdf).

Answer (score 4):

The question is not clear. If you are asking whether there are infinitely many pairs $(a,p)$ with $p$ prime such that $a^{p-1}\equiv1\pmod {p^2}$ then the answer is yes. For example, for $p=3$ this just asks for $a^2\equiv1\pmod9$, which is satisfied by $a=8,10,17,19,\dots$. For $p=5$, you want $a^4\equiv1\pmod{25}$, and any $a$ congruent to 1, 7, 18, or 24 modulo 25 will do. In general, any $a\equiv\pm1\pmod{p^2}$ will do.

If the question is whether, for fixed $a$, there are infinitely many $p$, see the comments by draks.

Comment: Yes, I mean for fixed a.I have edited the question.